# reverting to a previous commit using checkout removes omits some older commits git/smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm trying to get the code that I had 5 commits ago, and I'm doing that by going into the log and doing checkout on the specific commit, and I'm checking out this commit into a new branch

but the problem is that in the checked out branch in the log not all the previous commits (month old commits, way before the one that I checked out) aren't  present

*Edit* this is the commit that I'm checking out:
[image: smartgit log]

Comment: This is simply not possible, all commits know their parent(s) and once it's set it cannot be changed at all. [Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.](http://carm.org/extraordinary-claims-require-extraordinary-evidence) - can you reproduce this on a another repo? Or provide some more information - output of `git log` or `gitk --all` for example?

Comment: Please post screenshots illustrating the problem.

Comment: @mstrap I posted picture with the commit that I'm checking out emphasized

Comment: As you can see from the Log Graph, DJ-RemSmartThread contains possibly a lot of commits through merge sources which are not present in servthrottled. Hence, I'd say it's expected to not see these commits when just toggling servthrottled.

Comment: @mstrap yep, this is the answer

Comment: Another approach would be to locally revert your past five commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the Log Graph, `DJ-RemSmartThread` contains possibly a lot of commits through merge sources which are not present in `servthrottled`. Hence, it's expected to not see these commits when just toggling `servthrottled`, because they are most likely not reachable from this branch.